# inline schema is not supported with for xml path xmlschema

Tags: sql-server, xml, stored-procedures, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I would like to write a stored procedure as below in SQL Server.

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[Employee_delete]
AS

BEGIN
        SELECT * 
            FROM @employee
            FOR XML PATH(''), root ('EmployeeDelete'),xmlschema
END
```

But I'm getting the error--> 'inline schema is not supported with for xml path xmlschema'. May I know, how can I achieve XMLSchema with code "FOR XML PATH(''), root ('EmployeeDelete'),xmlschema"

To auto generate schemas in biztalk , I have to use word "xmlSchema"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are using BizTalk-2010 you should be using the WCF-SQL adapter for which you don't need to select as FOR XML to be able to generate schemas.

Answer (score -1):

Try...

```
FOR XML AUTO,ROOT('EmployeeDelete'), TYPE, ELEMENTS XSINIL, XMLSCHEMA
```

Comment: You should expand this answer to include *why* this fixes the problem.